# AIRMON-NG FROZEN LAPTOP

Tags: wireless, hp, monitor, airmon-ng

I have ubuntu when I do airmon-ng start wlo1 the computer freezes and won't move until I restart it! Can you help me?

Comment: are you trying to run on monitor mode ?

Comment: The problem still exists, when I type airmon-ng start wlo1 the computer freezes and I have to restart it from the button
I have ubuntu 20.04
phy0 wlo1 rtw_8723de Realtek

Answer (score 0):

1. There is another way to run monitor mode, and i also had few issues with airmon-ng with the wpa_supplicant service.
2. For monitor mode try the following commands:

   - `ip link set dev <interface> down`
   - `systemctl stop wpa_supplicant.service`
   - `systemctl mask wpa_supplicant.service`
   - `iw dev <interface> set type monitor`
   - 
3. For go back to managed mode run the following commands:

   - `ip link set dev <interface> down`
   - `systemctl unmask wpa_supplicant.service`
   - `iw dev <interface> set type managed`
4. Please let me know if that is working, if not please comment the following information:

   - specific ubuntu version.
   - specific interface.

Comment: The problem still exists, when I type airmon-ng start wlo1 the computer freezes and I have to restart it from the button
I have ubuntu 20.04
phy0 wlo1 rtw_8723de Realtek

Comment: my answer is giving another commands to run monitor mode, so you **do not have to use airmon-ng command**. if that wont work out you can try and execute `airmong-ng check kill` and then run the commands. **again, first try the answer i posted** and just then try the `check kill`.

Comment: i do .. still same problem .

Comment: i found this topic to the specific interface - give it a try <https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358075/realtek-rlt8812au-cant-start-monitor-mode>